# How can I reduce Windows 7 boot times?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, readyboost

I have a Sony VAIO laptop that has an i7 processor, 6 GB of RAM and a 7200 RPM 500 GB 2.5 inch drive.

I work in .NET, so I have SQL Server Developer, Visual Studio and a lot of other tools like that.

The machine takes nearly 4 minutes to boot up.  I actually timed it this morning and it is 2:45 seconds, although it is still isn't really responsive at that point.  It's clear things are still loading, in other words.

I have ReadyBoost but that doesn't seem to help.  Most of the boot up occurs before ReadyBoost even comes online, which is a shame because the flash memory for it is quite fast.

Is there a way to speed up the boot time and/or make ReadyBoost more effective?

Answer (score 18):

There is a freeware program called [Soluto](http://www.soluto.com/) which is claimed to speed up Windows boot time. It works for Windows 7. I haven't experienced it but I think it is worth trying in your case.

Comment: I have been using Soluto since early Alpha and am very pleased about the results. Initially lowered my boot time by 35%.

Comment: Ive tried Soluto, it's an easy way of filtering what starts at boot up and either stopping it altogether or deferring it to start after boot up.

Comment: So it turns out that a lot of the time in the boot was being taken by....Microsoft!  Microsoft Security Essentials AntiMalware was taking 30 seconds a boot.  Along with other programs, Soluto has taken my boot down to 1:55 from 4:04.

Comment: @rsteckly: 53% improvement is pretty good.

Comment: I lowered only ~2%. Probably because I already optimized my system as much as possible. (It's still "slow" because it's ~5 years old.)

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried running "[Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)"?

You could start with entries under "**Logon**".

> This utility, which has the most
>   comprehensive knowledge of
>   auto-starting locations of any startup
>   monitor, shows you what programs are
>   configured to run during system bootup
>   or login, and shows you the entries in
>   the order Windows processes them.
>   These programs include ones in your
>   startup folder, Run, RunOnce, and
>   other Registry keys. You can configure
>   Autoruns to show other locations,
>   including Explorer shell extensions,
>   toolbars, browser helper objects,
>   Winlogon notifications, auto-start
>   services, and much more. Autoruns goes
>   way beyond the MSConfig utility
>   bundled with Windows Me and XP.

[image]

Comment: Great for finding problematic items.  Often a conflict with two processes trying to start and one timing out. This tool will help but it will take some trial and error changes to the boot.

Answer (score 1):

4 minutes of boot time with those specs, means something is very wrong with your laptop. Has it always been that slow?

I strongly suggest making Sony take a good look at it just to make sure there are no hardware issues, if it is still covered by the warranty.

If there aren't any hardware issues, then try to format the hard drive and reinstall everything.

Upgrading to a SSD hard drive will give you the best possible speed boost, but at a cost. Alternatively, a hybrid drive such as a Seagate Momentus XT will give you some extra speed without breaking the bank.

Comment: It wasn't always that slow, but its never been fast either.  Honestly, I'm really dissatisfied with the product because it has known overheating issues and the fan comes on like the machine is going to blow up before the OS even starts!  That's just not reasonable.

Comment: Actually, the fan coming on hard is normal. The BIOS controls the fans on first start, and most systems I've worked with have spun the fans up to full speed before power management comes online and takes them down to normal speeds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows Performance Tools Kit to analyse your leak of boot performance. This tool give you detailed information about the Windows boot process. Take a look on google for it.... To understand the boot phases i recommend you look too for the "Windows On/Off Transictions". In this document Microsoft provides on them knowledge base descriptions about all phases and processes that needs to be booted on your system. I know a way to improve your system boot time using the Windows Performance Tool Kit, you can type the command: "xbootmgr -trace boot -prepSystem". It will boot up your computer for six times genarating prefetches for the boot process....

Comment: Here is a link to a optimization guide: [http://www.briteccomputers.co.uk/forum/tutorials-and-how-to/how-to-speed-up-boot-process-under-windows-vista-or-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

My answer from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/238745/tricks-to-speedup-startup-time-windows-7/238776#238776).

---

If I were you, I would check out **[TweakHound](http://www.tweakhound.com/windows7/tweaking/index.html)**. Determine how hard you want your machine tweaked (still pretty, or can you handle no-Aero?). They tell you what you're doing, and what'll be the side effects. You can disable extra services/startup items [which speeds your machine a lot], and they give you a list of what to disable, so you don't mess up your machine.

> Primum non nocere (First, do no harm) 
>   This guide is not a strip down the OS
>   to the bare bones gamers guide. The
>   intent of this guide is to allow you
>   to tweak the system while maintaining
>   full functionality. Yes, there is
>   stuff you can uninstall, turn off, or
>   disable and I will show you how to do
>   that. But (those who followed my
>   previous guides have seen this
>   before), there is one thing I would
>   like you to keep in mind. I've always
>   believed that Sir Isaac Newton's 3rd
>   Law, commonly phrased as "For every
>   action there is an equal and opposite
>   reaction" applies to just about
>   everything in life. It applies to
>   tweaking as well. Every time you make
>   a change it costs something. I'll let
>   you know what that something is. For
>   example, turning all the eye-candy off
>   can result in more available system
>   resources but may lessen the user
>   experience.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following reasons and try to fix them to reduce the boot up time for your laptop

1. Scan for Viruses & Malware
2. Change Boot Priority and Turn on Quick Boot in BIOS
3. Disable/Delay Startup Apps
4. Disable Nonessential Hardware
5. Hide Unused Fonts
6. No GUI Boot
7. Eliminate Boot Delays
8. Remove Crapware

Fixing the above things will surely help you to reduce the boot time as I reduced mine to 45 sec.