# Tricks to speedup startup time? Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reduce Windows 7 boot times?](https://superuser.com/questions/214675/how-can-i-reduce-windows-7-boot-times)

What can i do to make my computer load up faster? i could swear it was a lot faster in the past. My suspicion is the windows updates. Someone recommended soluto but it still takes over a minute 10 and i am sure it use to take <=45 seconds

Is there anything i could do? if i ever format my comp for any reason should i not get the window updates?
[image]

Comment: Don't stop installing Windows updates, whatever you do.

Comment: Is 1:18 really that bad, especially considering you’ve got several things auto-running? Someone is spoooiiiiled… `:-p` From what you’ve written in the question, it doesn’t sound like you changed anything. Soluto doesn’t automatically speed anything up, it just runs a trace to monitor the boot process and displays what runs and how long they take to do so. It’s then up to you to either disable things you don’t need or delay them for a bit.

Comment: @Synetech: Well considering it was half that before.....

Comment: Before what? You said it was faster “in the past”. No doubt you installed a bunch of programs since then. While the screenshot shows that most of the time 1:12.5 is from what looks like system stuff instead of programs, it isn’t. I promise that some of those items are due to third-party programs. Your best bet is to check the “new” services (the 9, 6, 6, and 5-second instances of `svchost`). Some of them are part of Windows, some of them are probably hosting some programs and/or drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the updates are the problem. The "53 applications run in your boot" may be more of an issue. Check out [Sysinternal's Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902). It can show you everything that's currently configured to run at boot time so you can selectively disable what you don't need (or at least what you don't need starting up **instantly** ).

[image]

A defragment once in a while doesn't hurt either ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would check out **[TweakHound](http://www.tweakhound.com/windows7/tweaking/index.html)**. Determine how hard you want your machine tweaked (still pretty, or can you handle no-Aero?). They tell you what you're doing, and what'll be the side effects. You can disable extra services/startup items [which speeds your machine a lot], and they give you a list of what to disable, so you don't mess up your machine.

> Primum non nocere (First, do no harm) 
>   This guide is not a strip down the OS
>   to the bare bones gamers guide. The
>   intent of this guide is to allow you
>   to tweak the system while maintaining
>   full functionality. Yes, there is
>   stuff you can uninstall, turn off, or
>   disable and I will show you how to do
>   that. But (those who followed my
>   previous guides have seen this
>   before), there is one thing I would
>   like you to keep in mind. I've always
>   believed that Sir Isaac Newton's 3rd
>   Law, commonly phrased as "For every
>   action there is an equal and opposite
>   reaction" applies to just about
>   everything in life. It applies to
>   tweaking as well. Every time you make
>   a change it costs something. I'll let
>   you know what that something is. For
>   example, turning all the eye-candy off
>   can result in more available system
>   resources but may lessen the user
>   experience.

Comment: No-Aero? Heck yeah! “Windows Classic” all the way. `:-)`

Comment: @Synetech The artist in me forbids going *that* far. :) I have, however, disabled Aero, and reverted to the "Windows Vista Basic" color scheme.

Comment: @Synetech BTW, I learned (a long while ago) that Aero relies on your Graphics card, so it eats up less CPU than normal GDI and stuff. (Randomly here because someone upvoted me in another one of my [answers](http://superuser.com/questions/214675/how-can-i-reduce-windows-7-boot-times/288204#288204).)

Comment: Yes, Aero uses the overlay surface (a.k.a., “hardware acceleration”), but only for the glass mode, not the Basic theme. When other programs (e.g., video players) need to use the overlay, Aero does that annoying flickering thing where it switches to the Basic theme then back to the glass theme when the other program ends.