# windows 7 start-up bottleneck

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reduce Windows 7 boot times?](https://superuser.com/questions/214675/how-can-i-reduce-windows-7-boot-times)

I'm tired of my Windows 7 taking too long to start. Is there any tool, that starts before all other services, and can measure time, that each service/autorun program takes to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Soluto](http://www.soluto.com/) should do the job..

Answer (score 0):

How long is long?  If it's slow to you, or slower than it was previously, it's likely because you have so many programs set to run at start up. To eliminate that situation, download, install and run autoruns.  You can get it here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.

Personally, I want only my anti virus and firewall to run at startup.  The rest start at my command.  I did have the MS mouse software set to run at startup for a while, but that was a total waste of resources.  Different strokes for different folks, but any computer will start faster once you relieve it of so many startup tasks.

Comment: 2:45, according to Soluto. Long enough, is it?

Comment: Anyway, thanks for link, that program of yous is pretty useful in displaying details.